# Adding characters to the end of multiple lines

Tags: replace, notepad++

I'm using Windows8.
So, this is what I have:

```
hello
```

this is what I want:

```
hello1
hello2
hello3
hello4
hello5
```

but with around 1500 numbers and the word isn't hello.
I'm not any programmer but I can use Notepad++, that's what I wanna use for this.
I don't wanna have to do `find: $` `replace with: 1` a thousand times.
I've searched for an answer for some time, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You will probably get better answers at [Super User](http://superuser.com/). Be sure to mention what OS you are using.

Comment: Stated what OS I'm using :)

Comment: do you want to rename folder names? dynamically, you can do that using php

Comment: Nope. It's a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I know you like Notepad++ and I do too, but I wonder if you couldn't solve this easier through PowerShell, which you already have installed by default in Windows 8.

This snippet will append an increasing number after "hello" from 1 to 3. You can easily change the quantity and the word. To run this script, just open the Start menu and type `powershell`, then paste the line below and click the green triangle (or hit enter if you opened the command prompt). I recommend you open the PowerShell ISE program, but the regular shell will work too.

```
1..3 | % { "hello{0}" -f $_ }
```

If you want to save this to a file, you could run this instead:

```
1..3 | % { "hello{0}" -f $_ } > C:\hello.txt
```

Congrats! You've written your first script!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in Notepad++ with the help of a plugin.  First, install the Python Script plugin from the Plugin Manager.  Next, create a new script from the plugin menu with the following code:

```
# First we'll start an undo action, then Ctrl-Z will undo the actions of the whole script
editor.beginUndoAction()

# Initialize counter to zero
counter = 0

# Define function to append incremental value to end of search result
def increment_counter(m):
    try:
        global counter
        counter += 1
        return m.group(0) + str(counter)
    except:
        return m.group(0)

# Search for value and replace with with appended incremental result
editor.pyreplace('^hello', increment_counter)

# End the undo action, so Ctrl-Z will undo the above two actions
editor.endUndoAction()
```

Next, modify the "hello" text for the text you wish to replace and save the script.  Finally, when you have selected the file in Notepad++ run your newly saved script.  Note that you can undo if the result is not as you wish.